# How to save data in BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

The user sets the date he wants to be notified in (receives a push notification that the movie is out) about a movie, for example. To do this I take the movie's ***id*** to set up the BroadcastReceiver and I also take the ***name*** of the movie; to use it as a text message for the broadcast receiver, for example, "movieName is out", with the method SetAlarm(). Note: my app doesn't have to do anything with movies, I'm speaking in general.

```
public void setAlarm(View view){

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);


    Intent alertIntent = new Intent(this, AlertReceiver.class);
    alertIntent.putExtra("id", mainId);
    alertIntent.putExtra("name", name);


    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);


    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, alertIntent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
}
```

As you can see I'm passing with an intent the id and the name of the movie to the AlertReceiver class

```
public class AlertReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    int id = intent.getIntExtra("id", 0);
    String name = intent.getStringExtra("name");
    createNotification(context, "Movie",  name + " Now Out" , name, id);
}

public void createNotification(Context context, String msg, String msgText, String msgAlert, int id){

    //intent for MainActivity
    PendingIntent notificIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(context, MainActivity.class), 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setContentTitle(msg)
            .setContentText(msgText)
            .setTicker(msgAlert)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

    //the intent when the notification is clicked on
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(notificIntent); //goes to MainActivity

    //how the user will be notified
    mBuilder.setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_LIGHTS);

    //stop notification when it's clicked on
    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);

    //now to notify the user with NotificationManager
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(id, mBuilder.build());
}
```

}

It works perfectly, the user gets notified only when the app is still running in the background, but after closing it or reboot, the broadcast receiver still gets called; the user gets notified, that means no problem with the ***id***, but the ***name*** is null, I get as a text message "null is out". So how can I save the name?

Answer (score -1):

Use `SharedPreference` to save the user name.

Comment: Ok, I'm really familiar with SharedPreferences, but how? And what do you mean by the user's name, do you mean the movie's name?

Comment: What if the name has a duplicate? My app isn't about movies

Comment: Save movie name and id while setting the alarm because when app not background the intent not having any bundle data so you need save the movie name in secondary storage

Comment: I would but i still have a problem, my SharedPreference gets overwritten for each movie I set a reminder too

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @krossovochkin do you know how I could do that? Do I need to declare a new SharedPreference for each movie I setAlarm() to? Then the BroadcastReceiver's OnReceive method will get the values out of the SharedPreference? Thanks!!

Comment: I agree with @stackvoid in general. I'm not sure one can give you better answer. You should store data somewhere? Then take a look at docs and all possible ways to do this (with examples): http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html I would prefer database, but it might be a little bit complicated. So, look at the docs, hope you'll find there something useful

Answer (score -1):

**SharedPreference**,**disk**,**database**...

recommend *SharedPreference*

Comment: How do I go on using one for my problem?